# how to check if '.'[dot] is present in string or not ? strstr is not working in php

Tags: php, strstr

I am trying to see if . [dot] is present in string or not.

I have tried strstr but it returns false.

here is my code :-

```
<?php
$str = strpos("true.story.bro", '.');
if($str === true)
{
        echo "OK";
} else {
        echo "No";
}
?>
```

I want to see if '.' is present in string or not, I can do with explode, but i want to do in 1 line, how could i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: `if($str === false)` is better - as `strpos` returns an index if it is not *false*. `if($str === false) echo 'No'; else echo 'OK';`

Comment: `strpos` will never return an explicit boolean `true` value.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You may use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php) directly.

```
if (strpos($mystring, ".") !== false) {
    //...
}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, `strpos` is a "confused?" int that return false if the needle part is not present in the sentence. Just pay attention to the operator `!==` that validate the type of strpos, as `!=` could also make this true if strpos return an int that can be equivalent to FALSE, which would be an error.

Answer (score 0):

Strpos returns the index of the first occurrence of the second argument in the first one. Use

```
$str !== false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using strpos incorrectly. It returns an integer of the first occurrence of the string and not `true` if it was found.

Try this code instead:

```
$str = strpos("true.story.bro", '.');
if($str !== false)
{
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "." is at the first byte in the string, `strpos` will correctly return zero. That inconveniently evaluates equal to `false`. Invert your logic like so:

```
<?php
$str = strpos("true.story.bro", '.');
if($str === false)
{
        echo "No";
} else {
        echo "OK";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

return of strpos is either integer(0 to strlen(string)-1) or boolean (false), then, you can check this using two cases:

```
$pos = strpos('this is text with . dot', '.');
if(is_int($pos)){
 echo 'dot is found';
}else{
 echo 'dot not found';
}

or 
if($pos === false){
 echo 'dot not found';
}else{
 echo 'dot found';
}

note strpos('. test', '.') = 0  then is_int(0) ?  true
```